# How to interact with deployed contract inside Brownie console

Tags: truffle, brownie

This is how I used to interact with deployed contracts when using `truffle console`

```
let contract = await Whitelist.deployed()
contract.getWhitelist()
```

However, I am now using a `brownie console` and this was the only way I was able to do the same.

NOTE: I freshly re-deployed the contract with  `brownie run deploy_contracts.py`

```
>>> contract = Whitelist.at("0x7CB3e6C814ddC99469B7e24271c90b9Aef610648")
>>> contract.getWhitelist()
```

Here it's obviously time-consuming to always have to search and paste an address inside a function.

Is there maybe an equivalent of `deployed()` command in the Brownie console that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a reference to your latest deployed contract with:

```
contract = Whitelist[-1]
```

Comment: Yeah, that might be it! I was trying to do it with Whitelist[0] but that didn't seem to work. I try to test it today and return back to accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you fire brownie console, you are firing it from the development network. Therefore, you will be unable to read deployed contract without changing the network first. Ensure you set the network to the designated testnet where your contract is deployed. You can do this as follow in the terminal:

1. In the terminal, write "brownie console --network rinkeby"
2. In my case the contract is simple storage so I wrote on the console: `from brownie import accounts, config, Storage as St, network`
3. Then I retrieve the information as simple as `simple_storage = St[-1].retrieve()`
4. You can do this print line as a check: `print(f"Address of this contract is {simple_storage}")`

Hope this helps